# Rails App Won't Start in Production Environment because of ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, postgresql-9.1, pg

I have repeatedly tried to setup my rails app on an ec2 instance using nginx and unicorn.  I have found that both nginx and unicorn are set up properly; however, on both machines my rails app does not want to start up in the production environment.  The output of attempting to start up in production is:

```
/Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:129:in `establish_connection'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:74:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  from /Users/benvreed/Documents/rubydev/StudyPublic/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
  from /Users/benvreed/Documents/rubydev/StudyPublic/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  from /Users/benvreed/Documents/rubydev/StudyPublic/config.ru:1:in `new'
  from /Users/benvreed/Documents/rubydev/StudyPublic/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  from script/rails:6:in `require'
  from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Although, I clearly do specify the postgresql adapter in my `database.yml` file:

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 8.2 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On Mac OS X with macports:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: study_development
  pool: 5

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # The server defaults to notice.
  #min_messages: warning

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: study_test
  pool: 5

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: study_production
  pool: 5
```

What's really strange is that it successfully runs in both the development and test environments.  I have checked other issues on StackOverflow and most have said that it is a spacing issue; however, I have redone the `database.yml` file several times with the same result.

My unicorn and nginx files are standard configurations.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am at a stand still until this runs.  Thanks in advance.

**RAILS_ENV**

When using the Rails Console by executing `RAILS_ENV=production rails c`, running `RAILS_ENV` produces:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant RAILS_ENV
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Rails.env produces:

```
=> "production"
```

Comment: Could you provide the value of your `RAILS_ENV` environment variable?

Comment: I provided the output above.

Comment: So the Rails console can be started but the server via unicorn and nginx could not be? I would start to dig at that part.

Comment: The server won't start in production using anything (attempted both unicorn and thin).  However, the production console will start up successfully. I don't know what could be causing this?

Comment: can you show the unicorn command, it may existed in your unicorn_init.sh file

Answer (score 1):

The adaptor in you database.yml should be pg, not postgresql.

```
production:
  adapter: pg
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: study_development
```

Answer (score 0):

My setup uses this:

```
production:
  adapter: pg
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: my_app_name_production
```

Comment: Attempted to use `adapter: pg`.  It responded: `/Users/benvreed/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': Please install the pg adapter: `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` (cannot load such file -- active_record/connection_adapters/pg_adapter) (LoadError)`.  I have the pg gem and postgresql installed.

Comment: What if you do `gem install activerecord-pg-adapter` anyway?

Comment: It tells me that it is not available. `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-pg-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository`

Comment: does `psql` get you a postgres prompt?

Comment: No, I have to specify `psql -h localhost`; otherwise, I get: `psql: could not connect to server: Permission denied
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: I would try adding a line for that, assuming 'host' would be used for 'h' and/or reinstalling postgres using different instructions or there is a (skip?) option to ignore the production area when compiling/running locally..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21658/discussion-between-michael-durrant-and-codeblooded)

Comment: Ok. I'm reinstalling Postgres now. Thanks.

Comment: Issues surrounding the user / postgres user are common with postgres

Answer (score 0):

Your database.yml settings is ok. Nothing weird.

If the development mode runs without exceptions, thus the problem is not in the DB.

Try to check database.yml precisely: maybe invalid/unacceptable* characters present.

---

- some symbols are so similar :) с and c

Answer (score 0):

Forking error! 
Maybe some caching or log problems It shows that nothing of the errors in our code.

My team resolve it.

- delete the project
- git clone the project
- config the database.yml
- start server

Everything is okay!

The same project the errors gone! 
So we think it is env problems or cach or log.

see here: (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18695551/edit)